# Formatting SprintF in C

Tags: c, formatting, printf

The question i have with the code below, is where i have used sprintf, i want it to insert a formatted int, because the client then picks up the data and pulls out data according to char array. So the client will pick up from the received code the delay from [0] and [1]. Where as another variable may be taken from the [2] and [3] that is sent from another bit of code. What is the way to format it like in printf to be saved in a char[]

```
int sock = *(int*)data->sock;
int i,startDelay =0; 
char buffer[SEND_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
puts("Run Machine Called");
for(startDelay=11;startDelay>=0;startDelay--)
{
    printf("Start Delay:%i\n",startDelay);
    sprintf(buffer,"%2i",startDelay);
    printf("Send Data - %2i - Start Delay\n",*buffer-'0');
    //write_sock(sock,buffer);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: What? Why `sprintf(buf, "%i", 42);` isn't good enough (**apart from the buffer overflow vulnerability**)?

Comment: If you want to have the number 0 padded from the left try format "%02d"... but I don't understand much the question...

Comment: basically my client needs to receive 11 0's every time it reads from the server. the first 2 will be one variable from the server, the 2nd set another variable and so on. if i just put startDelay into the char [] it may be '9' where i need it to be '09' as it needs to fill the 2 slots, is that better?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I *think* you're talking about a 2-byte (16-bit) integer value. If so, then `sprintf` is not the right tool for the job. Instead, you should take the integer and mask and shift to extract the 16 bits:

```
buffer[0] = startDelay & 0xFF; // low byte
buffer[1] = (startDelay >> 8) & 0xFF; // high byte
```

Of course, since your values are smaller than 255, the high byte here will always be zero, so it simplifies to:

```
buffer[0] = startDelay & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = 0;
```

It's not clear to me what the byte order should be, so you may have to reverse these and put the high byte in `buffer[0]` and the low byte in `buffer[1]`.